# Image not being saved to disk in android emulator

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to follow the google tutorial to take an image and save it to disk. I can take the image but when I go into the folder I don't find the image being saved.

MainActivity.java

```
// Copyright 2018 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

package com.horrible.wifipassocr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.horrible.wifipassocr.GraphicOverlay;
import com.horrible.wifipassocr.GraphicOverlay.Graphic;
import com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException;
import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelDataType;
import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions;
import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelInputs;
import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelInterpreter;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.document.FirebaseVisionDocumentText;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.document.FirebaseVisionDocumentTextRecognizer;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFace;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetector;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Button mTextButton;
    private Bitmap mSelectedImage;
    private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;
    // Max width (portrait mode)
    private Integer mImageMaxWidth;
    // Max height (portrait mode)
    private Integer mImageMaxHeight;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_pic);

        dispatchTakePictureIntent();

    }



    String currentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("Filename",currentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.d("IOEXCEPTION",ex.toString());
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.horrible.wifipassocr.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }


    /*@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            Log.d("ActivityResult","before image bitmap");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            Log.d("ActivityResult","finished with image bitmap");
        }
    }*/

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/image_pic"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Android Mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.horrible.wifipassocr">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.horrible.wifipassocr.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="."
        />
</paths>
```

The google tutorial can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

I couldn't follow their file-paths because it kept giving me a root cannot be configured error. The way I was able to fix it is by saying path="."

After the picture is taken I go into the folder that I printed out which in this case was: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.horrible.wifipassocr/files/Pictures/JPEG_20190316_192053_5929030357730379248.jpg but still don't see anything.

I don't know if it matters but I am using the Android studio emulator to do all this.